# How to turn a USB to a memory card for play station 2 (PS2)?

Tags: ps2

Is there anyway to REALLY turn a USB into a PS2 memory card?. I don't mean been able to transfer the files between a Memory Card and a USB with a CD that allows me to.

I am talking about have a game recognizing my USB as a memory and storing information there and/or have a game recognizing games previously saved (or transferred from a memory card or downloaded from internet) in my USB.

**P.S.:** One more thing just to be clearer, I am not talking about *boot* a game from a USB with a previously recorded ISO image on the USB.

Answer (score 1):

You can do this using a program called Open PS2 Loader, it will let you create virtual memory card images on a USB storage device. Unfortunately it doesn't seem to work with games loaded from disc. You have to boot the game from a USB drive, internal hard drive or network share.

Note that since it uses memory card images, not save games, it won't work directly with saves downloaded from the Internet. You'll need to move the save game to the virtual image before you can use it with the game, just like you would with a real memory card.

Comment: Can I have a detailed tutorial from the creation to the disc to a saved game example? Is that much to ask?.

Comment: @Hans Sorry, I've never used it. I've got plenty of real PS2 memory cards. Searching for "Open PS2 Loader tutorial" turns up a number of tutorials. Note your PS2 will need to be already capable of running homebrew software.

Comment: Link is dead. Please replace the link with a working one.